# Shiny, obtaining details from the plots

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed an application, where I am generating plots. I am able to render the plots and download it without any problem.

I would like to get the details of the points in the graph, when i move my cursor to the points. With search, I am not sure, if I can obtain this in Shiny.

Any help would be great.

Below is the code, i have used.

UI Code:

```
tabItem(tabName = "models2",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            infoBoxOutput("overview")
          ),
          fluidRow(
            actionButton("result1","Generate Result"),
            downloadButton('downloadPlot','Download Plot'),
            plotOutput("plot3")
          )
        ))
```

SERVER CODE

```
server <- function(input,output){
output$claim_overview <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste("91")," Overview",icon=icon("hourglass"),
      color="green"
    )
  })
  data<-  reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$result1,{

    data$plot <-   ggplot(data=timedata, aes(x=dat1, y=yes, group=3))+ 
      geom_point(shape=1)+
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(dat1_xlowlim,dat1_xhighlim))+
      labs(title="Prediction Probability",x="Reg.Date",y="True probability")  
  })
  output$plot3  <- renderPlot({ data$plot   })

  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function()
    {paste("input$plot3",'.png',sep='')
    },
    content = function(file){
      ggsave(file,plot = data$plot)

    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `brush` option or `hover` option to get any info from the plot.
Mouse hover example:

```
df<- table(rpois(100, 5))
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot", hover = "plot_hover"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "dftable"),
      br()
    )
  )    
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(df, type = "h", col = "red", lwd = 10)
  })

  output$dftable <- renderPrint({
    paste(input$plot_hover)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```